# Why are my filenames getting struck out when I switch to a new branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Filename getting struck out when I switch to a new branch:

[image]

I have also tried switch different branches, but still no use.

Comment: Because those files don't exist in the branch you've switched to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are "struck out" is that the branch you have moved to doesn't have those files. Even though they don't exist you still have them open on the IDE so it is telling you that they don't actually exist on this branch. If you close them you won't be able to open them again on this branch.